# Follower Table issue in user Database schema

Tags: database, schema

[user Database model][1]

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6345250684744630272

here is my database design for user I want to add user_ following table in this scenario can anyone help me to build user_follower table scheme?

Answer (score 0):

1- Each User has many other Users that followed him 
2- Each User can follow many Users

So you have a **many-to-many Unary relationship** on User in your ER.

Now, to **Mapping** this data model to Tables: 
 you can use a new table named: User_Followers and set 2 IDs of User as foreign key named source and target of following (and other attributes like date of follow and etc.)

you can find other mapping many-to-many Unary relationship (like Bit-Wise or Graph Data Models), but to your project, I offer as I mentioned.